# Xamarin AOT Compilation not possible because version code to high

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I get the following error message when I try to build my android application with the AOT option enabled.

```
Invalid command line switch for "aapt.exe". VersionCode is outside 0, 65535 interval
```

My normal version code is something like 20160524. Depending on the day I build it. For the play store this is fine. But it seems not so for the compiler. Since I already published an apk with this version I can't just make it lower. Is there an option to allow higher numbers as a version?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't precisely the same issue, as I didn't have AOT enabled, but I suddenly started getting this exact error after updating to a newer version of Xamarin.Android. I didn't change anything about my project files, but suddenly my version code of 220618, which used to be fine, was invalid.

I managed to resolve it by unchecking 'Generate one package (.apk) per selected ABI' in the 'Packaging' tab of 'Android Options' section in the project properties.

I would guess that checking this option makes something in the build scripts take a different path, which has a bug that causes this error. Enabling AOT compilation may use the same path (or perhaps implicitly enables the package-per-ABI option).